Prevent creating stylesheet file. ionic
I want to generate a new component without stylesheet file using schematics "ionic g c ..."
enter image description here
ionic Info

Ionic CLI                     : 7.2.0


Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 7.8.4


@angular-devkit/build-angular : 17.3.4


@angular-devkit/schematics    : 17.3.4


@angular/cli                  : 17.3.4


@ionic/angular-toolkit        : 11.0.1

I try adding options as "--inline-style=true" or "--skype-style=true" but don't work. Also i try to add to angular.json file the next:
"schematics": {
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit:component": {
      "skipStyle":true
    }
}


Does this answer your question? Angular / create a module, component without css file in one command?
